# How to pass input to the following code?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to pass an `input` like below.

```
    Input (stdin)
    1
    15
```

I am not sure how would i pass the above format `input` to my `_input` variable.

```
function processData(input) {
    //Enter your code here
   console.log(input);
} 

process.stdin.resume();
process.stdin.setEncoding("ascii");
_input = "";
process.stdin.on("data", function (input) {
    _input += input;
});

process.stdin.on("end", function () {
   processData(_input);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly you want. If you want to get the input from stdin and send _input to  processData function, you may use something like this. User can end giving input by just pressing the enter without typing.

```
function processData(input) {
    //Enter your code here
   console.log(input);
} 

process.stdin.resume();
process.stdin.setEncoding("ascii");
_input = "";
process.stdin.on("data", function (input) {
    if (input === '\n') {
      processData(_input);
      process.exit();
    }
    _input += input;
});
```